# Convert App to ARC while ignoring files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I want to convert my app to ARC but I have some external librarys and frameworks that are not complaint with ARC.  I know when yous start a new project using ARC, you can later specify which files to ignore.  But can you do this when upgrading an existing app to ARC?

Answer (score 9):

in XCode, go to your active target and select the `Build Phases` tab. In the `Compiler Flags` column, set `-fno-objc-arc` for each of the files you don't want ARC

EDIT:

Also, to have the opposite behavior, I mean to use a file that was written using ARC inside a non ARC project, you can set the file flag to `-fobjc-arc` instead

There is plenty of more info regarding `ARC` here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#general

Answer (score 1):

`ARC may be explicitly enabled with the compiler flag -fobjc-arc. It may also be explicitly disabled with the compiler flag -fno-objc-arc. The last of these two flags appearing on the compile line "wins".`

Source: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Answer (score 1):

To add to Felipe's answer, if you want to add this to multiple files at once:

Select all the files you want to exclude form ARC

Press 'Enter'

The pop-up box will appear at the last file in the list

Type `-fno-objc-arc`