# Not using the Automatic Reference Counting on a specific file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I pass to the Automatic Reference Counting on my ios5 app, but I have 2 or 3 file that they are so complicated to do the transition for the arc. So, is it possible to specified that a certain file will not use the arc?

Sorry for my very bad english... Hope you understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert App to ARC while ignoring files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335873/convert-app-to-arc-while-ignoring-files)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic Reference Counting for Some Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files)

Answer (score 6):

Go to your target > Build Phases > Compile sources and add the -fno-objc-arc flag to your files

Comment: When I add a flag to a file, after I did edit > refactor > convert to arc, but the flag that I added disappear and the file is still a problem, it seems like I must save after added a flag?

Comment: Just don't refractor your code. With this tag, your file (and only this file) is compiled without ARC.